# The Intersection of two periodic bullets at different speed?

Tags: math

I'm trying to find the mathematical equation or concept to calculate an intersection of two bullets at different speed.

It's like an intersection of two lines, but I'm trying to add time into it. So the lines still intersect, but it only counts at certain intervals (each different for each line). Which turns it into like bullets going at different speeds.

I feel like there's already formula for this because of air control are able to prevent flight collisions because of this. Or I'm just wrong and they are using some other algorithms to predict.

Comment: This feels like it is more a thing for [math.SE] than it is for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I belive that you can find more help on this topic in a more specilized site like http://physics.stackexchange.com/ or better http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ if I have understood your intention.

Comment: you solve the collision of the bullets paths, if they collide you check if the point of collision is at the same point in time for both bullets. this is straight forward if your bullets are points. you can extend this to any shape by checking all points on the first bullet (take its time of intersection with the path of the other bullet) and test if any point of the second bullet is equal to the intersection at that time. this is still easy for line segment bullets but gets much harder for areas/volumes...

Comment: Yes... I understand logically how the collision detection would occur. I'm trying to find the formula or the name of concept. For example pythagorean theorem. But I will ask in the physics section. Thank you.

Comment: By the way, for anyone else that is curious. Currently I'm planning to use the greatest common multiple to check for intersection. But that only works for parallel bullets. I'm not a math expert, so I get confuse when trying to incorporate it with cosine and sine. But i think I figure it out while typing this. Which is to compare the GCM for the two cosines and sines between its point to the intersection.

Comment: Look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34694101/collision-of-two-circles/34695279#34695279

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] or [physics.se] instead of programming or software development.

Comment: The concept is high school physics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching for "parabolic trajectory". The formula is

```
r(t) = -1/2 a*t^2 + v*t
```

where `r` is the position vector at time `t`, `a` is the (constant) acceleration vector and `v` is the velocity vector at time `t`. Write the same equation for both bullets (with different initial velocities). Knowing that in the case of a bullet the acceleration is vertical (and equal to g~=10), and knowing the initial velocity (its horizontal component remains constant), you can solve for `t` the resulting system of equations (x axis, y axis, and initial conditions).

Comment: Oh okay, thank you! And it describes the main application for parabolic trajectory calculations is calculating orbits which makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Of course 'orbit' is a general term, and if by 'periodic' you planetary-like trajectories, have a look at Kepler orbits. But the resolution technique is the same (solve both orbit equations for the same `t`).

Comment: g ~10 - units?  Important to know that it's 9.8 meters/second^2.  If you're going to go to the trouble of doing a delicate calculation, be as precise and accurate as you can.