# Vector2 intersection

Tags: math, intersection

I'm developing a little 2D game and i have to predict when and where things will collide.

So, i've got four Vector2 :

- A position
- B position
- A linear velocity
- B linear velocity

**I have to find if they intersect, where they intersect and at what time from now.**

I've found many math solutions but i could't translate them into code.

[The visualization of the problem, numbers are velocities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2fBU.png)

Comment: what are the lines, are they just trajectories of translation or an applied force ?

Comment: They are meant to be trajectories

Comment: tell me, you will use translation or applied force, because that will change the answer.

Comment: I'm using translation, the numbers represent the units of lenght / time(s)

Comment: If you're using Unity3D then why can't you use the 2D physics system (Box2D)?

Comment: I'm not using unity3d actually, something like it. And box2D can't tell me when the two vectors will collide before it happens

Comment: @Acerkacke The question is tagged with `unity3d`, however.

Comment: I know, but just because it's similar @trojanfoe, and someone using it can know the answer.

Comment: DON'T include a tag if it is not being used.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question for http://math.stackexchange.com and has no connection whatsoever to Stackoverflow.

Comment: I'm so sorry @JoeBlow, i was just trying to figure out how to translate this math into code.

Comment: You don't have to be sorry, it's just a shitty QA forum. it's just very likely it will be closed. note that you **ARE NOT** trying to 'convert mat to code'.  You are trying to **GET THE MATH**.  Note too that "convert math to code" questions are closed here

Comment: Look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34694101/collision-of-two-circles/34695279#34695279  (just exclude radiuses)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to compute the minimum of

```
norm((A+t*vA)-(B+t*vB))=norm((A-B)+t*(vA-vB))
```

Taking the square of these Euclidean norms

```
norm((A-B)+t*(vA-vB))^2 = norm(A-B)^2 + 2*t*dot(A-B,vA-vB) + t^2*norm(vA-vB)^2
```

gives you a simple quadratic function in `t` where the minimum has the value

```
min_dist =norm(A-B)^2 - dot(A-B,vA-vB)^2/norm(vA-vB)^2
```

at time

```
t = -dot(A-B,vA-vB)/norm(vA-vB)^2
```

Comment: Isn't t a vector too? Excuse me for my ignorance

Comment: No, `t` is the time, a scalar. `A,B,vA,vB` are the vectors of position and velocity.

Comment: I pasted the last line in my code and it gives me an error saying that vector3/vector3 = vector3 not a float. Sorry again.

Comment: a dot product is a float not a vector. Acerkacke, you need to VOTE UP the answer after the huge amount of effort made for you.

Comment: In `Vector3`, `dot(X,Y)` is `Vector3.Dot(X,Y)` and `norm(A-B)` is `(A-B).magnitude`.

Comment: Thank you so much, i thought that norm was the normalized vector, in fact that made no sense.
Thank you so much again @LutzL, you saved me.